# Android Studio Gives me : Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'RecyclerView.ViewHolder!'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

class DashboardRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardRecyclerAdapter.DashboardViewHolder>()

Error in the :- <DashboardRecyclerAdapter.DashboardViewHolder>

```
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.surajpatil.navigationdrawer1.R

class DashboardRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardRecyclerAdapter.DashboardViewHolder>(){

    class DashboardViewHolder(view:View)
    {
        val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecyclerRowItem)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup , viewType: Int): DashboardViewHolder {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DashboardViewHolder , position: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `DashboardViewHolder` does not inherit from `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. Have a look at the [docs for some examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter). It should look like this

```kotlin
class DashboardViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecyclerRowItem)
}
```